# XPath combine node sets

Tags: xpath

Let's say I have two expressions: `//div[@class="foo"]` and `//span[@class="foo"]`. Is it possible to "combine" them, like so:

```
//(div | span)[@class="foo"]
```

Or can I only take the union of the two complete expressions?

```
//div[@class="foo"] | //span[@class="foo"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more idiomatic (and dare I say readable) way to get all of the `div` and `span` elements having `class="foo"` is this:

```
//*[(self::div or self::span) and @class="foo"]
```

In English:

> Select all elements that are themselves a div or a span and that have a class attribute whose value is 'foo'

As for your original question, the following expressions return equivalent results:

1. `(//div | //span)[@class="foo"]`
2. `//div[@class="foo"] | //span[@class="foo"]`

The first gives you the set  that is the union of all the `div` and `span` elements in the document, further filtered to include only those having `class="foo"` while the latter gives you the union of 1) the set of all `div` elements having `class="foo"` and 2) the set of all `span` elements having `class="foo"`.

It should be fairly obvious that those two sets contain the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

This construct works:

```
(//golfer | //batter)[@ID="2" or @ID="3"]
```

...much to my astonishment.

Comment: `(//div | //span)[@class="foo"]` does too. Thanks!

Comment: Why is that astonishing? It's pretty straightforward, but not very idiomatic.

Comment: Note, of course, that `(//golfer | //batter)[@ID="2" or @ID="3"]` is not equivalent to `//golfer[@ID="2"] | //batter[@ID="3"]`. I mention it only because you chose to show an example that didn't really match the OP's original question, so that might be confusing in context with the equivalent expressions shown in my answer.